# How can I split a HAML template into different partials/includes in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, haml, partials

I am a PHP dev trying to start using HAML, using this implementation:
http://phphaml.sourceforge.net/

HAML looks awesome, but I don't understand if/how it supports partials (or includes, as they are called in the PHP world).

I would like to have a master template HAML file that then goes and loads up a bunch of partials for all the little pieces. (Then I can reuse those pieces in other templates too.)

In PHP or Ruby this would be really easy, is there any way to do this with HAML? thanks!

dylan

Comment: I don't think phpHaml supports this directly yet. But you can achieve something similar (but slightly different) using `display_haml` or write your own global `render_haml_partial` method - see my answer for details about what this method might look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite an old question, but I've updated the source code of phpHaml to reflect this new functionality!

Check out the commit @github
https://github.com/endorama/phphaml/commit/8d95d5ebff06275db8b14438e566c6e41ec91b7f

Comment: I just checked out the change to phpHaml. Thanks for incorporating this new method!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a global `render_haml_partial` method by analogy with phpHaml's existing `display_haml` method that might look something like:

```
function render_haml_partial($sFilename, $aVariables = array(), $sTmp = true, $bGPSSC = false)
{
    $sPath = realpath($sFilename);
    $haml = new HamlParser(dirname($sPath), $sTmp);
    $haml->append($GLOBALS);
    if ($bGPSSC)
    {
        $haml->append($_GET);
        $haml->append($_POST);
        $haml->append($_SESSION);
        $haml->append($_SERVER);
        $haml->append($_COOKIE);
    }
    $haml->append($aVariables);
    return $haml->fetch($sFilename);
}
```

This method could be placed in phpHaml's `HamlParser.class.php` file so it is available to all your templates.

The only difference between this and `display_haml` is that it invokes `fetch` instead of `display` at the end and returns the result so you can then insert it in-place into the invoking template.

You would then use it in your PHP/HAML templates as follows:

```
= render_haml_template("path to partial")
```

This would then be very similar to the Rails/HAML syntax:

```
= render :partial => 'path to partial'
```

Note that using `display_haml` directly does not have quite the same effect since it renders the template directly to the output instead of returning the result to the caller. Thus you could do the following:

```
- display_haml("path to partial")
```

But this doesn't capture the result of the render.

I'm guessing that somebody who cares enough about phpHaml might add such a `render_haml_partial` or something similar eventually - I might suggest it to the author some time.